# UIViewController trying to present modally

Tags: iphone

Trying to present UIViewController modally but it is working with only pushviewconttoller statement only.

```
 [navigationController pushViewController:_viewController animated:YES];
```

With presentModalViewController statement it shows only navigationbar that is it not done button not even UIView

```
[navigationController presentModalViewController:self.viewController animated:YES];
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not try to present a view modally by specifying the navigation controller as its parent. Try and present the view modally as an offshoot of your actual controller:

```
[myCtrl presentModalViewController:...];
```

I don't know in which context you are calling `presentModalViewController`; anyway, depending on the context, `myCtrl` could be `self`, or if you want that the modal view appear no matter which view controller is actually displayed you could try with:

```
[navigationController.topViewController presentModalViewController:...];
```